# DRY Rails routes for static pages inside scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, refactoring

I have many static pages for the docs. Currently I have defined the routes like this:

```
get 'docs' => 'docs#index'
scope path: 'docs', controller: 'docs' do
  get 'browser_support', action: 'browser_support', as: 'browser_support_docs'
  get 'getting_started', action: 'getting_started', as: 'getting_started_docs'
  get 'api_reference', action: 'api_reference', as: 'api_reference_docs' 
  # many, many others ...
end
```

Then I have created a `docs_controller.rb`where I have defined an empty action for each page. I can reference docs pages using `browser_support_docs_path` and similar.

Is there any way to dry up the above code? For example I have tried to add an `as: 'docs'` param to `scope` and remove it from the single actions, however that would generate ugly helpers like  `docs_browser_support_path`.

Comment: if the pages are static then you may go with this  [link](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage)

Comment: @GauravGupta Yes I've already seen that but I don't like it very much, I would prefer to use "vanilla" Rails